# Unexpected ionicons behaviour

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ionicons

Consider this [code](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xEyGXa).
I cannot figure out why it behaves as it does. All I need is the play icon alternating with pause icon everytime I click *anywhere* inside the `<td>`. It behaves as expected when I click inside the `<td>` but outside the icon itself. However, if I click on the icon itself, it behaves fine the first time, and then stops.

'The ionicon is wrapped in the `<a>` tag, which is a child of the `<td>` element. The event listener is on the `<td>`, so what could be the problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, figured it out. It seems like an artefact that arises from creating an element from a template and the way `mouseenter` is implemented.

The problem is that the `mouseenter` event (`hoverOn` part of the `.hover()`) triggers when it shouldn't. Each time a new ionicon is created from a template it will trigger the `mouseenter` event if the cursor moves a little.

Logically `mouseenter` shouldn't be triggered when the element appears, because `mouseenter` should trigger when a listener element or its descendent is hovered over, and then only call when the cursor leaves all of the elements associated with the event and then enters again. I think this is an artefact of creating an element from a template like that. Maybe it's because DOM get updated and it discards the fact that the cursor is already within the element. So `mouseenter` triggers again and in turn triggers creating a new play icon. Then it repeats..

This [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xEyGXa?editors=0001) should explain it well. If you hover over the play button the `mouseenter` counter will increment each time you move your mouse even a little, because each time a mouse is moved, a new play button is created. If you delete the line that creates a new play button, it behaves as mouseenter should, triggering only when the cursor enters the element.

Answer (score 1):

As @Vijai said your problem with the hover event .. And While I don't know a lot about your project and you really need `.empty()` on hover or you just need to `hide()` the icon .. You can try this part of code instead of yours

```
var hovOn = function(event) {
  if($(this).find('a').length < 1){
    $(this).html(playButtonTemplate);
  }else{
    $(this).find('a').show();
  }   
};
var hovOff = function(event) {
  $(this).find('a').hide();
}
```

[**Codepen Here**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KgGpEy)

Comment: Thanks, your answer is good and yes, hide() seems to be more suitable here, but my question is more theoretical, I'm trying to understand what could be the reason for it behaving as it does :/

Comment: @IvanInTheHat may be you can got the point by console.log('anything') in hovOn function .. and see the console when td hover , td click , a click

Answer (score 0):

When you click on the `<a>` tag it seems it is also triggering the parent `<td>` hover event. Once solution is try the below code for hover.

```
var hovOn = function(event) {
      if(playOrPause==='play') {

    $(this).html(pauseButtonTemplate);
    playOrPause = 'pause';
  } else {
    $(this).html(playButtonTemplate);
    playOrPause = 'play';
  }
};
```